# Chrome Extension Loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I currently have the code down below. However, this just keeps on looping and I don't know why it's happening.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    url = request.url;
    UName = request.username;
    PWord = request.password;
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (changeInfo) {  

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hello", username: UName, password: PWord}, function(response) {
            });
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener();
        return;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're sending a message from it to itself?

Comment: I'm sending a message from content.js to background.js and then after the redirect it sends a message back to content.js

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener` is not a [documented method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated). Instead of removing the listener you will probably have to use a variable to track if the callback has been executed yet.

Comment: But how would I remove the listener then?

Comment: Like I said, you would have to track a variable that tracks when you have already responded or not.